# Resources not updating after adding under web-app in spring boot

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

This is my folder structure. I'm using war build. When I'm uploading an image in my web-app/resources/img folder, I can't get this image without restarting my server. (getting 404 error) .
FYI, when I update any js file, I need to restart the server to get the update also.
I've tried some questions and solutions from SO and google. But those are not helping me.
If you need any other information, please comment. 
[image: folder stucture]

Comment: That's expected. You need to rebuild your war and redeploy it.

Comment: Is there any way to get the updated resources? It's annoying while working, you know.

Comment: You could put your resources into a regular directory. And don't forget to set spring.resources.cache-period

Comment: There are several ways: JRebel, using a proxy server which serves static resources from disk, using Spring developer tools (http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html), etc.

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet. I'll try them.
@Marged, do I need to update my resource handler? Now, It's like that.

registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/");

Comment: Check https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html, especially the static-locations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem has been solved with JRebel.
I've added extra configuration on Rebel.xml and put it in webapp directory.

```
<web>
    <link target="/">
        <dir name="G:/your_project_location/src/main/webapp"/>
    </link>
</web>
```

Comment: Share with us your jrebel.lic, please!! My evaluation license time is over and I need to using this amazing plugin for Intellij Idea

Comment: use my jrebel license. It's free.

Comment: I would apreciate if you send it me at tufao.agencia@gmail.com